# Python RegEx query missing overlapping substrings

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

Python3.3, OS X 7.5

I am attempting to locate all instances of a 4-character substring defined as follows:

- First character = 'N'
- Second character = Anything but 'P'
- Third character = 'S' or 'T'
- Fourth character = Anything but 'P'

My query looks like this:

```
re.findall(r"\N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]", text)
```

This is working except in one particular case where two substrings overlap. That case involves the following 5character substring:

```
'...NNTSY...'
```

The query catches the first 4-character substring ('NNTS'), but not the second 4-character substring ('NTSY').

This is my first attempt at regular expressions, and obviously I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if the re engine does not consume characters as it matches them, which is possible with lookahead assertions:

```
import re
text = '...NNTSY...'
for m in re.findall(r'(?=(N[A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z]))', text):
    print(m)
```

*Output:*

```
NNTS
NTSY
```

Having everything within the assertion works but also feels weird. Another way is taking the `N` out of the assertion:

```
for m in re.findall(r'(N(?=([A-OQ-Z][ST][A-OQ-Z])))', text):
    print(''.join(m))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Python 3 documentation (emphasis added):

```
$ python3 -c 'import re; help(re.findall)'
Help on function findall in module re:

findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

    If one or more capturing groups are present in the pattern, return
    a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
    has more than one group.

    Empty matches are included in the result.
```

If you want overlapping instances, use `regex.search()` in a loop.  You have to compile the regular expression because the API for non-compiled regular expressions doesn't take a parameter to specify the starting position.

```
def findall_overlapping(pattern, string, flags=0):
    """Find all matches, even ones that overlap."""
    regex = re.compile(pattern, flags)
    pos = 0
    while True:
        match = regex.search(string, pos)
        if not match:
            break
        yield match
        pos = match.start() + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(N[^P](?:S|T)[^P])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/fMCXOvfZ7-4ACmas)